# How to pass struct as argument

Tags: c, struct

I am writing a piece of C code, and I am supposed to use a static library, containing one function. I have a header file, containing a `typedef` struct, which I am supposed to use as input argument.

My understanding of the function is, that I create a structure of the data type defined in header file and give it as pointer to the function and the function will fill the structure. The other two arguments are `data` and `strlen(data)`.

My question is. How do I create the structure in my `.c` file and how do I get the data from it?

Here is a my .h file

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stddef.h>
typedef struct
{
  uint8_t arrayA[2];
  uint8_t arrayB[16];
} structDefinition;

void getData(structDefinition* myStructure, void const* data, size_t dataSize);
```

And this is my .c file

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include "myHeader.h"

structDefinition myStructure;

int main()
{
    char data[5] = {'123AF'};
    size_t dataSize = 5;

    getData(*myStructure, *data, dataSize);
    printf(mySignature.arrayA);
    printf(mySignature.arrayB);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: How is the function defined?

Comment: I would suggest reading the chapter about pointers in your beginner-level C programming book. And the chapter about arrays. And the chapter about strings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass the address of the structure for your function.

`myStructure` is a object of type `struct Definition`

Now pass

```
getData(&myStructure,data,dataSize);
```

`data` is an array of type `char` and it can be passed to a `char *`

Please check character array initialization

```
char data[6] = "123AF";/* char array comes with a nul terminator */
```

and length of the char array can be got from

```
size_t dataSize = strlen(data);
```

If you want to know the `strlen()` then 3rd parameter is not required.
Because you can get it from the string passed.

Comment: in C you can do `char data[5] = "123AF";` which gets no terminator, and use `sizeof data` instead of strlen

Comment: You don't actually need to pass the address of the structure, but in general it is advised to do so. BTW. it's good style to use definitions or, what I prefer, enums for constant sized data objects: `enum datasizes { DATASIZE=5, ASIZE=2, BSIZE=16 };`

Comment: @M.M What OP is trying to do is wrong. Hardcoding string length as well as initializing and also in C a string should be nul terminated for it be a valid string. I hope this is what OP wants

Comment: a constant sized data array is not necessarily a string, it's just a blob of memory with a constant amount of bytes in it, even if it is initialized as a string.

Comment: @ikrabbe If in the called API .If OP uses `data` as a normal string won't it lead to UB. Shouldn't the array be nul terminated?

Comment: @Gopi actually we don't know how op *uses* `data`, but only how he defines his array. BTW. the function name `getData` suggests that the data is only read from `myStructure` but we all can read from the context that it should better be called `setData`, as the data in `myStructure` seems to get modified by that function.

Answer (score 2):

This definition

```
char data[5] = {'123AF'};
```

is wrong. `'123AF'` is a character literal.. Its value is implementation defined. It seems you mean

```
char data[5] = { "123AF" };
```

where `"123AF"` is a string literal.

The function call

```
getData(*myStructure, *data, dataSize);
```

is also wrong. It must look like

```
getData( &myStructure, data, dataSize );
```

These output statements can be also wrong because it seems the arrays can contain characters without terminating zeroes

```
printf(mySignature.arrayA);
printf(mySignature.arrayB);
```

To output correctly these arrays you need to look through the definition of the function `getData` to determine how the arrays are assigned.

Comment: If in the called API .If OP uses `data` as a normal string won't it lead to UB. Shouldn't the array be nul terminated?

Comment: @Gopi In this case what is the purpose of the third parameter?:)

Comment: Yeah agree !! Just wanted to clarify .. But still we are not clear what OP is actually trying to do.. Only concern is in the called API the passed `const char *` shouldn't be used as a string

Comment: @Gopi Yes it is not clear how the function is defined.:)

Comment: `char data[5] = { "123AF" };` is also wrong. Should be `char data[5+1] = "123AF"`.

Comment: @Lundin You are wrong . It is a valid C initialization of a character array.

Comment: It is (unfortunately) valid C but most likely not the intent. If you wanted a raw character array instead of a string, you wouldn't use the `" "` initializer syntax.

Comment: @Lundin It is unknown how the function is defined. So it is difficult to say how the array should be initialized. Taking into account the third parameter of the function I assume that the second parameter is not necessary a string.

Comment: Given that the OP is a complete beginner, I think it is rather safe to assume that they want a string. At any rate, it can't be wrong to declare room for the null terminator, one extra byte of used RAM won't matter.